# How can i get all daily dates between two given dates in DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this DataFrame of Spark:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|       first       |        last       |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2022-11-03 00:00:00|2022-11-06 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I need to get the dates from the first, not including, to the last, including, jumping from day to day.

My desired output would be:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|       first       |        last       |                         array_dates                      
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|2022-11-03 00:00:00|2022-11-06 00:00:00| [2022-11-04 00:00:00, 2022-11-05 00:00:00, 2022-11-06 00:00:00] |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Is the issue on adding a new column? Or computing the list of days?

Comment: Hi @GaëlJ, the problem is adding a new column containing a calculated list of days. If possible, without using udf function.

Comment: Show us the code you tried then :)

Comment: I don't have a clear idea how to solve this problem without a udf function, that's why I asked

Comment: Why don't you want a UDF?

Comment: I would like to know if it can be done with spark functions to get better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spark, 2.4, you can use [sequence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#sequence(start:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,stop:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) built-in spark function as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, date_add, expr, sequence}

val result = df.withColumn(
  "array_dates", 
  sequence(
    date_add(col("first"), 1), 
    col("last"), 
    expr("INTERVAL 1 DAY")
  )
)
```

with following input `df`:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|first              |last               |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2022-11-03 00:00:00|2022-11-06 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

You get the following output `result`:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|first              |last               |array_dates                                                    |
+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|2022-11-03 00:00:00|2022-11-06 00:00:00|[2022-11-04 00:00:00, 2022-11-05 00:00:00, 2022-11-06 00:00:00]|
+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```